# Layout items stretching over graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I'm setting up a basic data entry form on my app but I'm having difficulty with the layout.

[image: stretching well beyond graphical layout]

That's the result of the graphical layout. It looks fine but all of the items are stretching well over the boundaries of the phone graphical layout. As a result the text from the button is gone and the spinners look stretched and unprofessional.

Here is the XML code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="#F3F3F3"
android:stretchColumns="1" >

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        style="@style/CustomText"
        android:text=""        
        android:id="@+id/nameContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/nameHint"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    </EditText>
    <!-- CUSTOM STYLES TO BE IMPLEMENTED FRIDAY! -->

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/type"
        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333">
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/type_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333">
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/descriptionContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:lines="5"
        android:hint="@string/descriptionHint">     
    </EditText>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
      <TextView
        android:text="@string/project"
        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#333">
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/type_project"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#ADD6AD"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_discard"
    android:textColor="#333"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    /> 

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSync"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#ADD6AD"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_save"
    android:text="@string/sync"
    android:textColor="#333" />
  </TableRow> 
 </TableLayout>`
```

Anyone got any idea how to remedy this error? I want everything to stay within the boundaries of the phone preview.

Comment: your coding works fine in my emulator

Comment: does it not stretch over at all? It works fine in the emulator it just stretches over the boundaries of it. Functionality wise its fine!